# what does &:hash means in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

The code is as below, and I am trying to understand that this specific code does `to_a.sort_by(&:hash).hash` in the Hash.hash method. What I do know is that, it first turns the hash into an array, sort the array, and then call the `hash` method on the `Array` class. I am trying to understand how exactly was the array sorted by?

```
class Fixnum
  # Fixnum#hash already implemented for you
end

class Array
  def hash
    each_with_index.inject(0) do |intermediate_hash, (el, i)|
      (el.hash + i.hash) ^ intermediate_hash
    end
  end
end

class Hash
  def hash
    to_a.sort_by(&:hash).hash
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is syntactic sugar for [Symbol#to_proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc).

In your concrete case the expansion would look like this:

```
to_a.sort_by { |e| e.hash }.hash
```

It other words it's sort the array by the [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-hash) value of its elements.